# Storing data from a button (datePicker)

Tags: android

The application being worked upon saves data locally. A form has been implemented and all its fields are to be saved.

For e.g.:

```
startdate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus) {
                if(!hasfocus){
                    EditText et = (EditText) v;
                    if(et.getText().toString().matches("")){
                        //do nothing
                    }else{
                        SM.set_value(SharePrefForproject.KEY_startdate, date2timeStamp(et.getText().toString()));
                        Log.i("StartDateCheck", date2timeStamp(et.getText().toString()));
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

where `startdate` is an editText element.

Likewise for checkBoxes the `setOnItemSelectListener` and for spinners an `setOnClickListener` is declared to record such data.

I am now having this confusion on how to store data generated by a `button`, which is a `datePicker`. Do I use the `OnFocusChangedListener` ?? Or do I do somethings else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use onDateSetListener.
This link might help you 
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/datepicker-and-timepicker-dialog-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a OnDateSetListener. There is an example in the android documentation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html